# How many 10-digit number such no digit occurs 4 or more times? (leading 0 not allowed)

Tags: combinatorics

I'm stuck here. My first approach was to enumerate the sample space: $10^{10}-10^{9}=9\cdot10^{9}$

From here, I just think of how many numbers have 4 or more of the same digit:

```
(_._._._).10.10.10.10.10.10
^repeated digits counting as one group.
```

But I think It's a wrong approach, because I will need to worry about duplicates. like (1111222234)

Can someone help? What could be a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Recommend approach via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  For each $i$ set event $A_i$ to be the event that the digit $i$ appears $4$ or more times.  Then $\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^9 A_i$ is the event that at least one number appears at least 4 times.  This is the complement of the event you want information about.

Comment: To count $|A_3|$ for example, you need to count how many have at least four 3's.  Breaking into cases based on the number of 3's used, and for each case picking the locations of the 3's and then the remaining numbers used, there are $\sum\limits_{k=4}^{10}\binom{10}{k}10^{10-k}$ if you don't care about leading zeroes.  If you do care about leading zeroes, then break further into cases based on if the first digit is or is not a 3.  For the intersection of two events, you'll range between all possible cases.  Note that the intersection of three events here is always empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If there are 25 or more digits for example. The approach would be the same? In this case there are an exponencial number of intersections and would be very dificult to solve this numerically.

Comment: Eventually it would be easier to do it directly, notice that with 31 or more digits the answer becomes zero.  I do not see at the moment a pleasant workaround that uses less case work I'm sorry to say, but that is not to say that a better approach doesn't exist, just that I haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@barakmanos has compiled the list of partitions of $10$ with all parts $\leq3$. There are $14$ such partitions, encoded as $$(x_k,y_k,z_k)\qquad(1\leq k\leq 14)\ ,$$ whereby $(x,y,z)$ denotes a partition of $10$ into $x$ parts of size $3$, $y$ parts of size $2$, and $z$ parts of size $1$, hence $3x+2y+z=10$.

Given such an $(x,y,z)$ we now count the number of strings, where $x$ digits appear $3$ times, $y$ digits appear $2$ times, and $z$ digits appear $1$ time, disregarding the condition that a string should not begin with $0$.

We can choose the involved digits in $${10\choose x}{10-x\choose y}{10-x-y\choose z}$$ ways, and when we have chosen these $x+y+z$ digits we can
arrange them in
$${10!\over 6^x 2^y 1^z}$$
ways. The total number $N_0$ of such strings is then given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^{14} {10\choose x_k}{10-x_k\choose y_k}{10-x_k-y_k\choose z_k}{10!\over 6^{x_k} 2^{y_k}}=8\,730\,489\,600\ .$$
Due to symmetry exactly one tenth of all these strings begin with a $0$. If we reject these strings we obtain the following number of admissible strings:
$$N={9\over10}N_0=7\,857\,440\,640\ .$$

Comment: I see that you've fixed my "$\frac{(x+y+z)!}{{x}!\times{y}!\times{z}!}$" mistake (your notation was my original idea, I tried to simplify it, and ended up with this wrong expression).

Comment: Thank you both barakmanos and christian-blatter, you've helped me a lot! I've got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we  ask about  $n$-digit numbers  in base  $b$ where  no digit
occurs more  than $k$ times. Observe  that the species of  ordered set
partitions into $q$ non-empty sets containing at most $k$ elements is

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=q}(\mathfrak{P}_{\le k}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

Therefore it has EGF

$$f_{q,k}(z) = \left(\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{z^p}{p!}\right)^q.$$

This implies that the number  $Q_n$ of $n$-digit strings (i.e. leading
zeroes allowed) is given by

$$Q_n = \sum_{q=1}^b {b\choose q} n! [z^n] f_{q,k}(z).$$

We  then obtain  for  $n$-digit  numbers (as  opposed  to strings)  by
symmetry the  value (we subtract  the number of strings  starting with
zero)

$$Q_n - \frac{1}{b} Q_n = \frac{b-1}{b} 
n! [z^n] \sum_{q=1}^b {b\choose q} f_{q,k}(z).$$

Now we have ${b\choose 0} f_{0,k}(z) = 1$ so $q=0$ does not contribute
to the coefficient on $[z^n]$ when $n\ge 1$ and we may write

$$\frac{b-1}{b} n! [z^n] 
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} f_{q,k}(z)
\\ = \frac{b-1}{b} n! [z^n] 
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} \left(\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{z^p}{p!}\right)^q
\\ = \frac{b-1}{b} n! [z^n] \left(\sum_{p=0}^k \frac{z^p}{p!}\right)^b.$$

In  particular we  have with  $b=10$ (decimal)  and $n=10$  (ten-digit
numbers) and $k=3$ (no digit occurs four or more times)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{7857440640.}$$

Observe that this last formula correspondes to the species

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=b}(\mathfrak{P}_{0\le\cdot\le k}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which says that  we have a sequence  of $b$ sets $D_m$  where each set
contains the  positions in  the $n$-digit string  where the  digit $m$
appears. We see  that the derivation then follows  by inspection.  The
initial  derivation  used  a  classification of  the  set  of  strings
according to the set of constituent digits.

The  Maple   code  including   a  total  enumeration   routine  for
verification was as follows.

```
EN :=
proc(n, b, k)
option remember;
local res, ind, d, dmset, kinst;

    res := 0;

    for ind from b^(n-1) to b^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, b);
        dmset := convert(d, `multiset`);

        kinst := max(seq(p[2], p in dmset));
        if kinst <= k then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;


X :=
proc(n, b, k)
    local gf;

    gf := expand(add(z^p/p!, p=0..k)^b);
    n!*(b-1)/b*coeff(gf, z, n);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Marko. I'm trying to understand using some other example ($n=18$, $b=10$, $k=3$). But I just didn't find how to calculate  $[z^{n}]$ nor $z$. Can you exaplain to me?

Comment: Wikipedia has this link on [EGFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function) and on [Formal Power Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients). We get for $X(18,10,3)$ the value $227485267000992000.$

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read the references you've sent, And try to reach this value.